# Advanced Rest Client VS browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest

The advanced rest client (Chrome) works for executing api call; but when I use jQuery's post method I get the error:

`Request header field Invoke-Control is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers`

Even in the response headers in the advanced rest client I do NOT see the header in the response.

Response Headers:

`Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Netepay-Password,User-Trace,Cancel-Any-Pending-Trans, Ancillary-Method`

Why would it work in the Chrome Advanced Rest client; but give an error when using JS? Are response headers optional when not using the browser?

I cannot share code due to NDA; but is it possible that the browser sandbox respects response headers; but the advanced rest client does NOT?